# Can you have notifications from realm based on another client update?

Tags: xamarin, realm

I am new to realm and using it via xamarin, my problem is that  when I started using realm I thought that realm objects will be auto updated by the server , but it turns out local realms are only updated if the client have a new update to push to his local object . Only then the realm is synced 
My question is  there is a way to update the local realm object in case of another Client  pushes an update to the server , can the sync action be triggered by the server?

Comment: (Assuming you are using Realm Platform and have a server running) So if your Realm clients have an active sync `Session` then changes on the server that need propagated to clients will happen automatically and thus your client's Realm is updated and you receive the standard change notifications

Comment: Well , it turns out that the sync session only sync if the client updated the realm remote object